# XCode 12 freezes after saving a file

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, xcode12

Context:

I am Running a SwiftUI Application on an iPhone 11 Pro Simulator, Previews are Turned off, After Recommendation from Apple Support team I have upgrade to XCode 12.3 from XCode 12.0.1.

Issue:

Since I have started using XCode for Swift, The Editor Randomly freezes once I save a file or open another file with the beach ball spinning. One answer on StackOverflow said that this might because Swift is a Strictly Typed Language and the Editor Reanalyses it every time you save a file. Previously I have used XCode with C++ and have never encountered this issue.

Computer Specs:

MacBook Pro (Late 2019) 128GB(30GB Free), 8GB RAM, i5 Processor. Simulator and XCode are the only applications that are open.

Comment: I had the same issue on an 2915 MacBook Pro. Turning off wireless connectivity to my iPhone, even though I was running tests on an iPhone 11 simulator, solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I fixed the problem:

- I deleted Xcode 12.3 which I downloaded from the App Store, went to the Apple Developer Downloads Website: https://developer.apple.com/downloads and downloaded Xcode 12.2, I installed it and done! Everything was working seamlessly even at peak conditions.